# How to see the activity menu of a specific extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to add a shortcut to show the activity menu of `gruntfuggly.todo-tree` extension in the activity bar. For the other ones I have something like this:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+e",
    "command": "workbench.view.explorer"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+g",
    "command": "workbench.view.scm"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+d",
    "command": "workbench.view.debug"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+x",
    "command": "workbench.extensions.action.showInstalledExtensions"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+t",
    "command": "workbench.view.todo-tree"
  },
```

but I do not know what command use to that specific extension. Any idea? Where can I look up these commands? I would like to do it with `ms-azuretools.vscode-docker` extension too.

EDIT: I'm referring to this menu:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I had to open [an issue in the vscode repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101232#issuecomment-652260183). It looks like there's a view command for every extension added automatically. You only need to open the Keyboard Shortcuts and type `workbench.view.extension.` and look for the name of the desired extension.